# Server.Transfer shows duplicate pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a call to method DoSomething() in my page load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DoSomething();        
    }
    catch
    {
        Server.Transfer('~/Error.aspx');
    }
}
```

Now problem is `DoSomething` also does a `Server.Transfer` to `Error.aspx` if some condition is not met and meanwhile if my `Page_Load` also throws exception, that also does a `Server.Transfer`.
Now I get duplicate error pages shown in browser.
 How do I stop this?
 I want that no matter if I write `Server.Transfer` 5 times, it should only show the error page once and not show duplicate pages in 1 page.

Comment: What you try to explain here? put your whole code here.or use
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectpermanent.aspx

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi: Do you know there is a difference between Redirect and Transfer?

Comment: @nunespascal: Yes, that would definitely help. I was thinking if there is some better so I don't have to have flags everywhere on each page.

Comment: Sounds like you need to rethink the way you are exception handling...

Comment: Respose.redirect
---------------------------------------------------
Respose.redirect can use another appliaction url.
It has round trip.
Its much slower than server.transfer.
 
Server.transfer
---------------------------------------------------
In server.transfer we can use with in that application only.
It has not round trip.
it has faster than response.redirect

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi: Glad you came to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm.. how about DoSomthing() should return a boolean that tells you if it already issued a server transfer?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool serverTransferToErrorPage;
    try
    {
    serverTransferToErrorPage = DoSomething();
    // some more code that may throw execpetions..
         // ...
         // ...
    }
    catch
    {
    if(!serverTransferToErrorPage)
        Server.Transfer('~/Error.aspx');
    }
}
```

And ofcourse your "DoSomthing()" method should look somthing like that:

```
private bool DoSomthing()
{
   try
   {
      return false;
   }
   catch
   {
      Server.Transfer('~/Error.aspx');
      return true;
   }
}
```